# How can I feed batch CSV data for tensorflow learning

Tags: csv, tensorflow, tensorboard

Thanks for read my question

I have data like these.
19 data for input and 1 for label

I already had tried mnist, tensorboard example and csv batch load example.
Now I'm trying mixed it all.

load csv data and make it batch.
learn just 1 layer and check cost.
that is all I want to do

this is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.name_scope("input") as scope:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 19])

with tf.name_scope("weight") as scope:
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([19, 1]))

with tf.name_scope("bias") as scope:
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))   

with tf.name_scope("layer1") as scope:
    y = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

w_hist = tf.summary.histogram("weight", W) 
b_hist = tf.summary.histogram("bias", b) 
y_hist = tf.summary.histogram("y", y) 

with tf.name_scope("y_") as scope:                              
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

with tf.name_scope("cost") as scope:
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y),  reduction_indices=[1]))
cost_sum = tf.summary.scalar("cost",cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope("train") as scope:    
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)


def read_my_file_format(filename_queue):

    reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1)    

    _, value = reader.read(filename_queue)

    record_defaults = [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1],[1], [1], [1], [1], [1],[1], [1], [1], [1], [1],[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]] 

    record_defaults = [tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), 
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32),  
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), 
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32),
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32),  
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), 
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), 
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32),  
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), 
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32),  
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), 
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32),  
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), 
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32),
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32),  
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), 
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), 
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32),  
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), 
                   tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32)] 

col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15 ,col16, col17, col18, col19, col20  = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)    

    features = tf.pack([col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14, col15 ,col16, col17, col18, col19])
    label = tf.pack([col20])  

    return features, label  


def input_pipeline(batch_size, num_epochs=None):

    min_after_dequeue = 10000
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["sampledata1999_2008.csv"], num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)

    example, label = read_my_file_format(filename_queue)     


    example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([example, label], 
                                                     batch_size=batch_size, 
                                                     capacity=capacity, 
                                                     min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)    
return example_batch, label_batch    

examples, labels = input_pipeline(100,1)

init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())

sess = tf.Session()

# Initialize the variables (like the epoch counter).    
sess.run(init_op)

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
trainwriter =tf.summary.FileWriter("./board/custom", sess.graph)

# Start input enqueue threads.
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

try:
    i = 0;
    while not coord.should_stop():
        i = i + 1
        example_batch, label_batch = sess.run([examples, labels])
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: example_batch, y_: label_batch})        
        if i % 100 == 0:
            summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={x: example_batch, y_: label_batch})
            trainwriter.add_summary(summary,i)             
            print(example_batch)       

except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
finally:
    # When done, ask the threads to stop.
    coord.request_stop()

# Wait for threads to finish.
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

I checked batch data correctly feed to the cross_entropy.
but If i use these

```
    if i % 100 == 0:
        summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={x: example_batch, y_: label_batch})
        trainwriter.add_summary(summary,i)             
        print(example_batch)
```

I had Got a error message like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1020     try:
-> 1021       return fn(*args)
   1022     except errors.OpError as e:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1002                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1003                                  status, run_metadata)
   1004 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     65             try:
---> 66                 next(self.gen)
     67             except StopIteration:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    468           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 469           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    470   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: weight_1
     [[Node: weight_1 = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](weight_1/tag, weight/Variable/read)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d641bed636e8> in <module>()
    104         example_batch, label_batch = sess.run([examples, labels])
    105         sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: example_batch, y_: label_batch})
--> 106         summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={x: example_batch, y_: label_batch})
    107         writer.add_summary(summary,i)
    108         print(example_batch)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    764     try:
    765       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 766                          run_metadata_ptr)
    767       if run_metadata:
    768         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    962     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    963       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 964                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    965     else:
    966       results = []

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1012     if handle is None:
   1013       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1014                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1015     else:
   1016       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1032         except KeyError:
   1033           pass
-> 1034       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1035 
   1036   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: weight_1
     [[Node: weight_1 = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](weight_1/tag, weight/Variable/read)]]

Caused by op 'weight_1', defined at:
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2821, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-d641bed636e8>", line 17, in <module>
    w_hist = tf.summary.histogram("weight", W)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\summary\summary.py", line 205, in histogram
    tag=scope.rstrip('/'), values=values, name=scope)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_logging_ops.py", line 139, in _histogram_summary
    name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary histogram for: weight_1
     [[Node: weight_1 = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](weight_1/tag, weight/Variable/read)]]
```

what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that is wrong with your code is the initialization of your weights... You should give them random weights (otherwise your network will not learn). The summary talks about there being a NaN (Not a number) in your weights. Try running W.eval() to see what exactly is in your weights matrix!

Comment: I had checked W.eval()

Comment: There is NAN value so I assign W value again. and check W value again but still W value is NAN